# Error of installing Google Chrome in Centos 7

Tags: google-chrome, installation, centos7, yum

I followed the following steps to install Chrome in my Centos 7 system.

```
(base) [abc@bogon ~]wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
(base) [abc@bogon ~]sudo yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_*.rpm
```

All was OK, but I got the following error while I run  "google-chrome &".

```
(base) [abc@bogon ~]$ google-chrome &
[1] 4679
(base) [abc@bogon ~]$ /usr/bin/google-chrome: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/google-chrome: undefined symbol: gbm_bo_get_modifier
```

I could not launch Chrome. How can I fix this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a missing symbol in the libgbm library. You will likely need to update the mesa-libgbm package to a later version.

- `sudo apt update mesa-libgbm`
- `sudo yum update mesa-libgbm`

Or the equivalent for your OS.